# Web application transfer data on button push

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm writing my very first C# web application and have a problem on how to update the intial values declared in my class.

A simple example to illustrate the problem:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public int x = 1;

        public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LabelLoadOnly.Text = x.ToString();
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LabelButton1.Text = x.ToString();
        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int y = x + 1;
            LabelButton2.Text = y.ToString();
            x = y;
        }
    }
}
```

Initially, x = 1. When pushing Button 2 I want to increase x by 1. This works ok the on the first button push but not the second...

How do I update my _Default.x ?

Answer (score 2):

use something like

```
 LabelButton2.Text = int.Parse(labelButton2.Text)+1;
```

also your LabelLoadOnly should be protected by

```
if(!IsPostback){
...
```

Comment: ok, this will work. Thank you.My idea is to use a text box where the user input a % and the label will then be updated by x*%. If I don't store x somewhere this will be lost when the % value is changed...  I guess it will be possible to use a hidden label or similar to store the value of x.

Comment: You can store x in a hidden value or Session["MyValue"]=x; and read it back when you want

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in an ASP.Net application, that instance of the page lives just long enough to serve a single request. When the postback happens (you click the button), you get a fresh instance, with `x` reset to 1.

Ways around it are [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstate.aspx) and/or [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.session.aspx), depending on how long you want to keep the value. Do **not** use static variables: they may seem to work when debugging, but *all* users will share the same value - usually not what you want!